# mysql left outer join returns all rows, ignores specified field value

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables in a MySQL database:

```
cellphone table
ID
phone_number

verification_code table
ID
verification_codes
code_expires
code_used
```

I'm trying to query for a specific ID in the cellphone table, and I want to get that row whether or not they have a valid verification code.

Here is my query

```
SELECT a.ID, a.phone_number, b.verification_code, b.code_expires
FROM cellphone a
LEFT OUTER JOIN verification_codes b ON (a.ID = b.ID
  and a.ID = '12345'
  and b.code_expires > NOW()
  and b.code_used IS NULL)
```

Instead of getting just the ID I'm looking for, I get a huge recordset that includes ALL ID numbers. Can someone help me format this query correctly?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: A foreign key should have a name like `cellphone_id`. `verification_code.ID` should be the unique ID in that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions on the *first* table in the `left join` go in the `where` clause.  Conditions in the *second* go in the `on`:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.phone_number, vc.verification_code, vc.code_expires
FROM cellphone c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     verification_codes vc
     ON c.ID = vc.ID AND  vc.code_expires > NOW() and vc.code_used IS NULL
WHERE c.ID = '12345';  -- single quotes are unnecessary if the id is a number
```

The reason is simple.  A `left join` keeps *all* rows in the first table regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to true, false, or `NULL`.  This is true even for conditions on the first table.  Hence, conditions on the first table of a `left join` are effectively ignored when they are in the `on` clause.